# Adding app from Project Task list saved template

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-template, ms-project

I have a SharePoint Project Tasks file that is synced up with a local MS Project file.  I saved a template of this list as a backup and wanted to restore it.  Ive uploaded the .stp to my List Templates folder but it is not showing when I go to "Add an App".  Looking into it a bit further, it seems that this type of list template is hidden by default, so even though it is uploaded correctly I am unable to add it in like I would with any regular custom list template.

So, is there anyway to make this type of template available so I can then add it to my site?

Comment: Did you found any solution? I am also facing same problem.

Comment: I ended up working with MS on this.  Turns out that the issue was that I was using Project 2010 with SP 2013.  I was told that the problem would not have existed had I used Project 2013, although I haven't verified if thats the case since the data was lost and the people working on it decided to go another route..  In any case, you can rename the .stp to .cab and then extract and modify the manifest.xml file....but doing so wont allow the solution to be installed in this case.